# IntelliJ external library dependence within packages

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Within an IntelliJ project, I have set up a dependence on an external library (project structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Add -> Library). This library appears in the "External Libraries" tab on the left.

For classes which are placed directly in the src directory this works fine.

However, for packages I create within the project, IntelliJ doesn't recognize functions from the external library (I get a red line and a "cannot resolve symbol").

How should I set up the external library so that this issue is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
2. In the left-hand pane of the dialog, select Modules.
3. In the pane to the right, select the module of interest.
4. In the right-hand part of the dialog, on the Module page, select the Dependencies tab.
5. On the Dependencies tab, click add and select Jars or directories.
6. In the dialog that opens, select the necessary files and folders. These may be individual .class, .java, .jar and .zip files, and the directories containing such files. Click OK.
7. If necessary, select the Export option and change the dependency scope.

8.Click OK in the Project Structure dialog.

[Source](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html)